# Devise Rails: Do not allow users to login whose role field is empty or nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise for authentication, it's working fine. My `users` table contains a `role` attribute. I want to not allow login for users whose role field is empty or nil.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

One way to conditionally allow user login is by overriding Devise's `#active_for_authentication?` method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && role.present?
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can validate this on the ApplicationController, like:

```
before_action :validate_user_role

...

def validate_user_role
  flash[:alert] == "User don't have a Role"
  redirect_to login_path if current_user.role.blank?
end
...
```